# disable cshtml error

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Does anyone know how can I disable to see cshtml files, e.g `/Views/anything.cshtml`? I got 404, The resource cannot be found error message.
I use Umbraco 7.

Comment: Thats not possible. You need to create a controller and then render your razor view. Or create an .aspx page.

Comment: Are you asking how to render a custom 404 page?

Comment: I already have custom 404 page, but that doesn't work with these cshtml. But yes, basically that is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you need. But you can omit specific URLs by defining it in the web.config:

```
<add key="umbracoReservedUrls" value="~/config/splashes/booting.aspx,~/install/default.aspx,~/config/splashes/noNodes.aspx,~/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd,~/log.aspx,/Views/anything.cshtml" />
```

Comment: Sorry, probably it wasn't clear. What I meant, the site is working, but when I type something like this `/Views/Master.cshtml` or `/Views/blabla.cshtml`, I got an error message:
`Server Error in '/' Application.The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404....`
I would like to hide it.